# Some libraries can read my JPEG image but some can't. How to fix my JPEG image without re-encode it?

Tags: c#, image, itext, jpeg

I have some JPEG images in byte arrays that may have minor corruptions. I am using iText 7 to insert them into PDFs.

These images are accepted by `System.Drawing.Image` and all my image processing programs, but strangely not accepted by `iText.IO.Image.ImageDataFactory.Create()`.

I can use `System.Drawing.Image.Save()` to re-encoded them, which does work, but I suspect that the corruptions are very minor and doesn't need re-encoding. One of the JPEGs is in the following with Base 64 encoding. Could you help me find the problems of this image?

```
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
```

Comment: question: is it really worth the effort instead of simply re-encoding and being done with it? also: if some code created slightly corrupted images, wouldn't it be more sensible to fix the code instead of the images?

Comment: @FranzGleichmann Good question. Maybe I should add some more details.